# How to search for a word in Word2Vec model

Tags: python, word2vec

We were given an assignment to research codes and methods to solve "Author Name Disambiguation". I was trying to understand the code provided by "joe817" on GitHub, the repository's link is:

https://github.com/joe817/name-disambiguation

I installed all the requirements and was successful to run the first file "data processing.py", but the second file "DRLgru.py" shows me an error at line 43, saying the model (Word2Vec model) is not iterable. I googled the issue to find and helpful documentation but was not able to find any.

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCDsk.png)

Could someone please help me clear this error?

This is the code:

```
num_step = 20 #GRU时序个数
word_input = 100

paperid_title = {}
with open("gene/paper_title.txt",encoding = 'utf-8') as adictfile:      #opening a file
for line in adictfile:                                                  #for loop on each line
    toks = line.strip().split("\t")                                     #First remove spaces with strip then split into tuple around \t
    if len(toks) == 2:
        paperid_title[toks[0]] = toks[1]                                # Assign a paper name to the id before it {'id' : 'paper_name'}

save_model_name = "gene/word2vec.model"
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load(save_model_name)                         # Loading a pre-defined model

paper_vec={}
paper_len={}
for paperid in paperid_title:                                           # looping on dictinory id's in paperid_title
split_cut = paperid_title[paperid].split()                              # make a list which contains each word of title
words_vec = []
for j in split_cut:
    if (len(words_vec)<num_step) and (j in model):
        words_vec.append(model[j])
```

Comment: Can you show the full error, with traceback stack, as quoted text rather than a screenshot? (See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 for more on why this is important.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it (somewhat). The issue was related to using the newer version of the package, whereas the code was for the older version. So I used google collab to choose an older version of the package.

Comment: Please make sure your answers are helpful to others. At the very least include details on the exact versions and why the other version doesn't work